# Тип TEXT вместо VARCHAR(N). Быстродействие и компактность

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица товаров с множеством полей. Для текстовых данных (название, автор, ссылка на картинку и т.д.) используется тип VARCHAR(N). Длина N для каждого поля задана на основе предполагаемой средней длины + 20-30% запаса, так как неизвестно насколько длинными будут вставляемые записи.

Поиск по текстовым полям не ведется. Поиск осуществляется по числовым проиндексированным полям.

Как повлияет на компактность таблицы и на быстродействие, если для текстовых данных вместо VARCHAR(N) буду использовать тип TEXT?

Comment: Абсолютно то же самое, если N>256. Или text на 1 байт длиннее, если N для varchar < 256.

Comment: Тогда почему mySQL не дает создать поля VARCHAR(N1),VARCHAR(N2)... таблицы суммарной длинной больше 65535? N1+N2+... >65535

Comment: Думаю из за пережитков прошлого. В большинстве форматов хранения таблиц InnoDB varchar так же как text выносятся из записи, если длина  начинает превышать 768 байт. (Я надеюсь, что MyISAM вы не используете). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html

Comment: потестил производиотельность InnoDB и MyISAM на своем проекте (чтение случайных записей из достаточно большой таблицы). Оказалось InnoDB работает у меня на ~5-10% быстрее. Да и проблемы с MyISAM были. На больших таблицах, при интенсивной записи таблица иногда рушилась.